# How to use Cloudflare 1.1.1.1 with Kubernetes DNS

Tags: kubernetes, dns, cloudflare, nameservers, coredns

I'd like to use Cloudflare's [1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1](https://1.1.1.1/) nameservers in Kubernetes, alongside [DNS over TLS](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-tls/). It [looks like](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/) I can do it using [core-dns](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/1650). I need to setup the following somehow:

- IPv4: `1.1.1.1` and `1.0.0.1`
- IPv6: `2606:4700:4700::1111` and `2606:4700:4700::1001`
- TLS Server Name: `tls.cloudflare-dns.com`

What should my `ConfigMap` look like? I've started it below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  upstreamNameservers: |
    ["1.1.1.1", "1.0.0.1"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure your core-dns `kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap coredns`
and add to end of corefile:

```
. {
    forward . tls://1.1.1.1 tls://1.0.0.1 {
       tls_servername cloudflare-dns.com
       health_check 5s
    }
    cache 30
}
```

and than save new configuration and restart core-dns pods.

```
kubectl get pod -n kube-system | grep core-dns | cut -d " " -f1 - | xargs -n1 -P 10 kubectl delete pod -n kube-system
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using a `ConfigMap` that is a bit more friendly? Also, does Core-DNS support IPv6?

Comment: using `kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap coredns` you ipdate configmap, about IPv6 Idont think so because Kubernetes doesnt support IPv6 fully.

Comment: Is there a way to patch a `ConfigMap` to provide only pieces of config that you want to change? I want to do this through CI/CD if possible to make things repeatable and `kubectl edit` is not great for that.

Comment: this is a `kube-system` namespace. so If you want to add some CI/CD update this configmap you have to change it in place where you store code for your infrastructure for example KOPS store it in s3 bucket on AWS. if you don't manage your `kube-system` namespace just update your current setup and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

## Azure AKS Only Answer

This is copied straight from [Azure AKS releases](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/releases).

With kube-dns, there was an undocumented feature where it supported two config maps allowing users to perform DNS overrides/stub domains, and other customizations. With the conversion to CoreDNS, this functionality was lost - CoreDNS only supports a single config map. With the hotfix above, AKS now has a work around to meet the same level of customization. Here is the equivalent ConfigMap for CoreDNS:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns-custom
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  azurestack.server: |
    azurestack.local:53 {
        forward . tls://1.1.1.1 tls://1.0.0.1 {
          tls_servername cloudflare-dns.com
          health_check 5s
        }
        cache 30
    }
```

After create the config map, you will need to delete the CoreDNS deployment to force-load the new config.

```
kubectl -n kube-system delete po -l k8s-app=kube-dns
```